# Removing the fill color of a cell that has a specific RGB in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a better way to remove a specific fill color of a cell.
Currently, I'm checking each cell of each sheet and if it matches the color I wanted, then I remove it.
But my problem is my macro needs to do it to 100s of file, and it's taking too long.

```vb
Dim cellRange as Range
Dim currWorksheet As Worksheet

For Each cellRange In currWorksheet.UsedRange
    If cellRange.Interior.Color = RGB(xxx,xxx,xxx) THEN
        cellRange.Interior.Color = xlNone
    End if
Next cellRange
```

Comment: I think you should define the condition based on a certain color value. Try to write the macro:
If Colorindex = 15 (example of your color index) then entirerow.delete

Comment: @MKR Currently, that's how I code it. I added some code snippets on how it  looks